# Is it possible to project onto face during snapping in the direction of the cursor?

Tags: snapping, 3d-cursor, axis

I would like to project the vertices of an object onto the surface of an other. I know how to do that using the snapping tool. However, a drawback of this method is that vertices are only projected according to the point of view. Instead, I would like them to be projected according to an imaginary axis going from them to the cursor location.

Example : If I surround a cube with a sphere, I would like to be able to project at same time all the vertices of the sphere onto the faces of my cube, and this way, reshape my sphere as a cube.

Does someone know an already implemented way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: for the example it looks like what you're looking for is the Shrinkwrap modifier but I'm not sure as it is not what you describe at first

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images to illustrate the question. Some of us have a rather bad imagination.

Comment: Shrinkwrap tool is exactly what I was looking for ! I struggle during 2 hours trying to achieve this effect with snapping and it was just under my nose. I feel a little stupid ^^'

Thank you very much